# Terraform Kubernetes provider fails on Github Action with following: 'config_path' refers to an invalid path: "/github/home/.kube/config"

Tags: github, kubernetes, terraform, github-actions, minikube

I am trying to create a CI build in Github Actions for Kubernetes deployment with Terraform on Minikube. The Terraform apply fails on deploying provider with following message:

```
Invalid attribute in provider configuration

  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes"],
  on providers.tf line 18, in provider "kubernetes":
  18: provider "kubernetes" {

'config_path' refers to an invalid path: "/github/home/.kube/config": stat
/github/home/.kube/config: no such file or directory
```

How can I resolve it? I have tried various approaches but so far nothing works. Everything works fine when I deploy it locally with Minikube.

Relevant code snippets from Terraform:

variables.tf:

```
variable "kube_config" {
  type    = string
  default = "~/.kube/config"
}
```

providers.tf:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = pathexpand(var.kube_config)
  config_context = "minikube"
}
```

Github Actions job:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup minikube
      uses: manusa/actions-setup-minikube@v2.7.2
      with:
        minikube version: 'v1.28.0'
        kubernetes version: 'v1.25.4'
        github token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        driver: docker
        container runtime: docker

    - name: terraform-apply
      uses: dflook/terraform-apply@v1.29.1
      with:
          path: terraform-k8s
          auto_approve: true
```

I have also tried running it with official setup-minikube action, but doesn't work as well.

Comment: Are you able to run `kubectl` commands like `kubectl get nodes` or  `kubectl get pods` before the `terraform-apply`?

Comment: Yes I can. I have included additional action `- name: kubectl run: kubectl get pods -A` for testing after setup-minikube and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I have managed to make it work by using official Hashicorp's action instead of the original. Gonna check if it deploys everything in the end :)

```
    - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2   
    - name: terraform-init
      run: terraform -chdir=terraform-k8s init
    - name: terraform-apply
      run: terraform -chdir=terraform-k8s apply -auto-approve
```